# Utilisation de "y réfléchir" ?

Tags: grammaire, usage

Can I use y *réfléchir* in context of studying ? For example, a teacher asks me if I understood the grammar concept and I reply,

> Non maintenant, je dois y réfléchir un peu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *réfléchir* can be used in the context of studying but that might not be the best choice in your sentence:

> *— Tu as compris l'accord du participe passé ?*
>
> *— Pas encore, il faut que je travaille encore un peu.*

but

> *— Peux-tu dire comment accorder "plaire" dans "elle s'est plu" ?*
>
> *— Pas maintenant, je dois encore (y) réfléchir un peu.*